# Angular2 vs Rails Api vs Facebook Auth

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth-facebook

I am using a rails api with devise gem to login to facebook. When i use a link from an html under the rails app directly to login. It works perfectly.
Now if i try to move to a client with angular2 and call the same route in the rails app. The problem occur in the redirect to facebook. I can hit the route cause i have already setuped "cors rack gem" but when behind the scene "devise gem" call the facebook api the origin for this call is null. I didn't find a way to get it work after 3h searching.

anyone setuped angular (1 or 2) with rails api and devise/omniauth?

the rails api and the angular app are under different domain

Comment: Hey @naskaa if I understand you correctly you want to perform the social login without leaving the application (i.e. changing pages), is that correct?

Comment: I want to move the html code from the rails app to an angular2 client. 
I was able to login from the rails app (html under rails app) but if i call the same route with ajax from the angular app it fail. 
I am  able to do cross domain call between my angularApp and the Api. The only exception is this login route because the rails app call it self an external domain facebook (devise gem) and in this call the origin in the request header is "null".

Comment: But you want to avoid getting redirected or what? I'm not sure I understand the problem with moving around the html. What I think you may be doing is trying to use angular http services `$http.get` etc. but this will produce a problem when Facebook tries to redirect the user. Facebook expects a physical page redirect because they will need to do things like security prompting etc. But you would be able to do something like open the rails route in a new window and closing it after passing auth data (which you could do using an encrypted websocket).

Comment: Yeah, I just re-read your comment. You can't use ajax to call a facebook redirect for the reasons I explain above. If that were possible to do, Facebook would have no way to control security and permissions prompting.

Comment: i can let my login page in the rails app then. and after the user creation i redirect to my main page in the angular2 app. It's not the best approach cause i by pass the problem but i can move on.

i posted to understand the token based auth.
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/858

 i ll change in the futur probably for this approach
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I endup using this gem for token based auth.
https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

I have removed devise totally from my gem file and i am using only "devise_token_auth" now.

You need to use a frontend library as for angular1
https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth to call the api.

In my case i just used the demo from ng-token-auth, i extract the parameters from the call to register and used this parameters in a normal ajax call in my angular2 app => i was able to create a user.

normally devise_token_auth handle facebook proprely for ajax call (didn't try it yet)

Comment: how did you get ng token auth to work with angular 2??? i'm having trouble with this

Comment: sorry didn't see your question. no need to answer that anymore you can use: https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token